# Two way data binding with Vuex-ORM

Tags: vue.js, vuex, 2-way-object-databinding, vuex-orm

Does anybody know of a library or an already described pattern for achieving two way data binding in forms when using [Vuex ORM](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/)?

I've found a couple of libraries for helping with this with Vuex, but none specifically for Vuex-ORM yet:

- [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields)
- [vuex-pathify](https://github.com/davestewart/vuex-pathify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any predefined plugin to do this, but you should be able to do the same for typical Vuex states using setter and getter on computed property...?

```js
import User from '@/models/User'

export default {
  computed: {
    user: {
      get () {
        return User.find(1)
      },

      set (value) {
        User.update({
          where: 1,
          data: {
            name: value
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KiaIshii. I'm hoping to find a way to do this without repeating myself for every field in potentially large forms. Have only recently starting using the Vue ecosystem, but if I come up with a clean solution, I'll be sure to share it for comment!

Comment: Thanks! That would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Following [Kia Ishii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443061/kia-ishii)'s idea, I came up with a function that I invoke to generate computed properties for all fields of a vuex-orm model. Because I use uuids, I can use `insertOrUpdate`.

This function creates a configuration for a Vue Component that reads and writes fields from a vuex-orm Model. The configuration contains computed properties for all fields of the model, to allow two-way data bindings with the v-model attribute. It also contains a props option with an id field, so the component needs to be associated with a router-view.

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

/**
 * @param {typeof import("@vuex-orm/core").Model} model
 * @returns {{props: Object, computed: Object}}
 * @this {VueComponent}
 */
export default model => {

  const fields = model.fields();
  const computed = {};
  for (const field in fields) {
    if (field !== 'id') {
      computed[field] = {
        get() {
          const item = model.find(this.$props.id);
          return item ? item[field] : fields[field].value;
        },
        set(value) {
          model.insertOrUpdate({
            data: {
              id: this.$props.id,
              [field]: value
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        default: uuidv4
      }
    },
    computed
  };

};
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this @ahocevar, looks quite useful. Suggest adding an example of its invocation within a component also. After posting this question, I also came up with a somewhat similar solution, based off of the vuex-map-fields library. I've been wanting to polish it a little before posting it back here, but yours looks good too.