# Vuex-ORM two-way-data binding cannot watch a nested object

Tags: vue.js, vuex, two-way-binding, vuex-orm

this question is related to [Two way data binding with Vuex-ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218760/two-way-data-binding-with-vuex-orm)

i tried using a `watch` with `deep` to handle a user form like this.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div style="display: inline-grid">
      <label for="text-1">Text-1: </label>
      <input name="text-1" type="text" v-model="user.name" />

      <label for="text-2">Text-2: </label>
      <input name="text-2" type="text" v-model="user.lastName" />

      <label for="text-3">Text-3: </label>
      <input name="text-3" type="text" v-model="user.birth" />

      <label for="text-4">Text-4: </label>
      <input name="text-4" type="text" v-model="user.hobby" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Result</h5>
      {{ userFromStore }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      userFromStore: "getUserFromStore",
      messageFromStore: "getMessage",
    }),
    user: function () {
      return this.userFromStore ?? {}; // basically "User.find(this.userId)" inside store getters
    },
  },
  watch: {
    user: {
      handler(value) {
        console.log('called')
      //  this.updateUser(value);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchUser: "fetchUser",
    }),
    ...mapMutations({
      updateUser: "updateUser",
    }),
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchUser();
  },
};
</script>
```

problem is my watcher is not watching, no matter what i try. as soon as the data came from Vuex-ORM my component is not able to watch on the `getters` `user`

Anyone idea why?

Comment: How do you mutate your object ? There are some caveats for object modification detection in Vue2: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: yeah i removed the mutation inside the watch. The problem is, i don't even come to the point where the mutation gets triggered. the watcher is doing nothing on input changes

Comment: It's not the mutation inside of the `watch`, it's the mutation that should trigger the `watch` that you should look for.

Comment: @kissu it could be that ORM is adding the data dynamically into my store getter and it destroys my reactivity.

Comment: @kissu any hint for where to look for the `watch` mutation?

Comment: Not sure how vuex ORM works, but why do you not watch for `userFromStore` directly ?  Let's remove the behavior of the `computed` from the equation. Also, quick tip, you can write all your vuex getters/actions and so on, like this: `...mapGetters(['getUserFromStore'])` rather than the object form, if you do not want to rename it.

Comment: Maybe this thread can be somehow helpful: https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/issues/197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.find(...)` returns a model. The properties of that model are not reactive i.e. you cannot perform two-way data binding on items that are not being tracked. Hence your watcher will not trigger.

My advice would be to push your user data as props to a component that can handle the data programmatically.

Or, by way of example, you can simply handle two-way binding manually:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

class User extends VuexORM.Model {
  static entity = 'users'

  static fields() {
    return {
      id: this.number(null),
      name: this.string(''),
      lastName: this.string(''),
      birth: this.string(''),
      hobby: this.string('')
    }
  }
}

const db = new VuexORM.Database()
db.register(User)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [VuexORM.install(db)]
})

User.insert({
  data: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    birth: '12/12/2012',
    hobby: 'This, that, the other'
  }
})

Vue.component('user-input', {
  props: {
    value: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  template: `<input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" placeholder="Enter text here...">`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    user() {
      return User.find(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(prop, value) {
      this.user.$update({
        [prop]: value
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuex-orm/core@0.36.4/dist/vuex-orm.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="user" style="display: inline-grid">
    <label for="text-1">Name: </label>
    <user-input
      id="text-1"
      :value="user.name"
      @input="update('name', $event)"
    ></user-input>

    <label for="text-2">Last name: </label>
    <user-input
      id="text-2"
      :value="user.lastName"
      @input="update('lastName', $event)"
    ></user-input>

    <label for="text-3">D.O.B: </label>
    <user-input
      id="text-3"
      :value="user.birth"
      @input="update('birth', $event)"
    ></user-input>

    <label for="text-4">Hobby: </label>
    <user-input
      id="text-4"
      :value="user.hobby"
      @input="update('hobby', $event)"
    ></user-input>
  </div>
  <pre>User in store: {{ user }}</pre>
</div>
```